# How to get professional help in OR

Tags: optimization

I would like to hire a consultant at OR to do a formulation of a mathematical optimization problem. Which website is reliable for it?

Comment: There are several companies providing OR services. For example, most of the French ones can be found among the partners of the French OR society https://www.roadef.org/roadef-partenaires For companies from other countries, I don't know if there is a list somewhere. It might be worth checking the website of the local OR societies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you my bias opinion because I am freelancer ( I don't know anything about other specific OR websites, linkedin, glassdoor, recruitment agencies or networking methods ) but  if I were you my mainly choices were:

- [Fiverr.com](https://www.fiverr.com/) you can check [here](https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?query=operations%20research&source=top-bar&search_in=everywhere&search-autocomplete-original-term=operations%20research) for specific OP expert, 194 OP freelancer working there.
- [Upwork.com](https://www.upwork.com/) you can check [here](https://www.upwork.com/hire/operations-research-freelancers/) 239 OP specialist working there.
- [Guru.com](http://guru.com/)
- [Toptal.com](http://toptal.com)
- [PeopleperHour.com](https://www.peopleperhour.com)

Also you have to check his portfolio, last work done and reputation there are a lot of scammers and difficult people for both parts working freelance.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the list that is on Gurobi's website:
https://www.gurobi.com/partners/consulting-services/.